# Html is small when the device is less than 370px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As you can see in the attached image, using the chrome f12, when lowering the pixels to less than 380px or so the page html does not cover the entire screen and there are white lines to the right side that the more the larger screen is made. How can I fix this and that the error is due?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n94Rz.jpg
Thank you very much.

Comment: you have to post your code, html and css

Answer (score 0):

The problem was i had 2 images with no styles yet , and these were afecting all the design of the page. Thanks.